# What this artifact is due to?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

My solidify modifier thickness is very less. However, I am pretty confident this to be a modeling issue but cannot figure out the problem. White is the intended outline (rim light kind of) but that green thick highlight not what I want.
[image]

Here is the part file link. Thank you :) https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8nJZnesg

[image: Scene Setup]
[image: Model in Wireframe Mode]

Comment: Hello, please add a screenshot of your scene, with every object. Might be something else from the scene reflecting from the surface of the bottle, or it might be light refracting inside the material of the bottle

Comment: Ok. Let me add them too. I have added blend file link also

Comment: You have a spotlight directly behind the bottle, if you disable it or turn down its power does it fix the green bands ?

Comment: Yes. It does. But then it removes the white highlight also.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the reason was unnecessary solidify modifier I used. Removing it helped and after it was all about adjusting light coming through the bottle.